# What's the return value of the ternary operation "?:"?

Tags: c

My classmate asked me a question:

What's the value of x,y,z after this:

```
x=5;
y=8;
z=((x++)<(y++)?(x++):(y++));
```

I 'm not sure about it, so I tested it and answer is:

```
x=7,y=9,z=6
```

I can understand why "x=7" and "y=9", but why "z=6" ? Shouldn't this expression return the value calculated by "x++" ?

Thanks for help :)

Comment: "ternary", not "trinocular". "ocular" means vision so, unless you're some bug-eyed monster from Tau Ceti, that won't apply to you :-)

Comment: The value calculated by the second `x++` is 6; that's why `z` gets assigned 6.  The value in `x` after it is 7, but post-increment means that the value before the increment is assigned to `z`.

Comment: oh again sequence point........>>!!!

Comment: @Coaku Can you kindly accept the answer if it helped!

Comment: @Pavan Manjunath Oh,sorry, I just forgot it,thanks for mention ! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) between the evaluation of the first operand of `?` operator and second or third operator and hence first `x++` would completely take effect resulting in x=6. But the increment in the second `x++` would take effect only after the evaluation of the complete expression as there are no more sequence points in that expression and hence x remains 6 and z=6.